# redirect unknown address in traefik

Tags: redirect, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm, traefik

How to setup up traefik to redirect all unknown addresses? What I mean is the following - I use docker swarm with traefik and I have couple of services with rules set up in labels:

- `` "traefik.http.routers.app.rule=Host(`app.example.com`)" ``
- `` "traefik.http.routers.else.rule=Host(`else.example.com`)" ``
- etc.

What I want is to **handle requests for which no matching rule is found**, e.g. `lalala.example.com` -> `example.com`.

I tried to add the following in my traefik container labels section:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.default.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.default.entrypoints=web,websecure"
- "traefik.http.routers.default.priority=1"
- "traefik.http.routers.default.middlewares=default-redirect"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.default-redirect.redirectregex.regex=.*"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.default-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=https://example.com"
```

However, this doesn't work, each attempt to request non-existent address ends with:

```
Websites prove their identity via certificates. Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for lalala.example.com. The certificate is only valid for <some_random_id>.traefik.default.
 
Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

Letsencrypt works fine on my existing services and I'm also redirecting all http to https if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following labels to set the redirections via middleware

```
- traefik.http.middlewares.default_host.redirectregex.regex=^https://(.*)?example.com(.*)$$
- traefik.http.middlewares.default_host.redirectregex.replacement=https://example.com
- traefik.http.middlewares.default_host.redirectregex.permanent=true
- traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{any:.+}`)
- traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.entrypoints=web,websecure
- traefik.http.routers.http_catchall.middlewares=bevision
```

You also need to make sure that lets encrypt can handle SSL certs for all domains (You need a wildcard cert for this)

```
- traefik.http.routers.wildcard.tls=true
- traefik.http.routers.wildcard.tls.certresolver=route53
- traefik.http.routers.wildcard.tls.domains[0].main=example.com
- traefik.http.routers.wildcard.tls.domains[0].sans=*.example.com
```